# Sockjs - Send message to sockjs-tornado in Python code

Tags: python, django, websocket

I use `https://github.com/mrjoes/sockjs-tornado` for a Django app. I can send messages from javascript console very easy. But I want to create a signal in Django and send json string once the signal is active.

Could anyone give me a way to send a certain message in Python to sockjs-tornado socket server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are few options how to handle it:

1. Create simple REST API in your Tornado server and post your updates from Django using this API;
2. Use Redis. Tornado can subscribe to the update key and Django can publish updates to this key when something happens;
3. Use ZeroMQ (AMQP, etc) to send updates from the Django to the Tornado backend (variation of the 1 and 2).

In most of the cases, it is either first or second option. Some people prefer using 3rd option though.

Comment: Actually, I started writing the app using  `https://github.com/liris/websocket-client` to connect to Sockjs-tonardo via `hybi-13`. But your recommendations are still cool. I like them :)

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote [djazator](https://github.com/mike-grayhat/djazator), simple and easy to use django plugin. It uses zeromq for delivering messages from django to sockjs-tornado. Additionally, it can send messages to subset of authenticated django users.

Answer (score 0):

I just put this up https://github.com/amagee/sockjs-client for talking directly to a SockJS server from Python (using xhr streaming).